# How to send xml in socket connection

Tags: java, android, serversocket

I wrote a socket connection in android and want to send the xml over that.
following is my socket programming

```
   @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String modifiedSentence;
    try {
        String message ;
        message ="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body><sendrecv> <eventList><eventName>event</eventName> <eventName>event</eventName> <eventName>event</eventName></eventList> </sendrecv></body>";

        Log.d("String to send",message.toString());

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.200", SERVERPORT);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        Log.d(TAG,"TCP Connected.");
        outToServer.writeBytes(message);
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        Log.d(TAG,modifiedSentence);
        Log.d(TAG,"sucess");

       /* clientSocket.close();*/

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TCP Error: ",e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I think this data is not being send to server because sever is not responding to this request..
Is there any other way to send xml ?

**Permission in androidManifest permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Working code in c++ platform QT  client side**

```
int received;
unsigned char header [4];
int len;
int sent;
unsigned char recvbuf[2048];
unsigned int payload_len;


  sprintf (sendbuf, "%s", "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"\
                                    "<body>"\
                                        "<sendrecv>"\
                                            "<eventList>"\
                                                "<eventName>event1</eventName>"\
                                                "<eventName>event2</eventName>"\
                                                "<eventName>event3</eventName>"\
                                            "</eventList>"\
                                        "</sendrecv>"\
                                    "</body>");
}
len = strlen ((const char*)sendbuf);
header[0] = (unsigned char) (len >> 24);
header[1] = (unsigned char) (len >> 16);
header[2] = (unsigned char) (len >> 8);
header[3] = (unsigned char) len;
weht_writen(s.clientfd, header,4);
weht_writen(s.clientfd, (unsigned char*)sendbuf,len);

 memset (header, 0x0, 4);
received= weht_readn(s.clientfd,header,4);
if(received<0)
{
    qDebug()<<"Failed to read registration message header";
    return;
}

payload_len   = header[0];
payload_len <<= 8;
payload_len  |= header[1];
payload_len <<= 8;
payload_len  |= header[2];
payload_len <<= 8;
payload_len  |= header[3]; 
received= weht_readn(s.clientfd,recvbuf,payload_len);
```

Comment: have you set permissions in the manifest file to allow your application to connect to the network ?

Comment: How is the server reading the data? If it's expecting a line, you aren't sending one.

Comment: server expecting the whole xml and will send the response behalf of that before that server sould know that how many character it has to read..so my question is how to tell server that read up to this character

Comment: @EJP I have working code in QT meaning c++ I can post it here the same thing I need to do in java but I dont understand c++..

Comment: `server sould know that how many character it has to read`. Use DataOutputStream:writeUTF(str) as its sends the size first.

Comment: `how to tell server that read up to this character` ??? Which character? You did not mention any character before.

Comment: I mean whole xml which is in message String

Comment: Do you have C++ code for the server or the client?

Comment: @greenapps `writeUTF()` requires `readUTF()` at the other end, and the other end isn't Java, and the other end needs 32 bits of length, not 16.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428075/how-to-send-xml-data-through-socket-inputstream this what I have to do for my question..

Comment: @EJP, how would you know that the other end needs 32 bits without seeing code? I posted my question before OP posted code. I asked for code.

Comment: I posted that after seeing the code, but in any case unless you know the server is written in Java the recommendation isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The working client code you have finally posted sends a 32-bit length word in network byte order before the data. You aren't sending that. You need to send it using `DataOutputStream.writeInt()` before sending the data. You should have been informed of this, or informed yourself, before you started coding the client.

Comment: code what ever I have posted in c++ is not sever side
that code is working code in client side.

Comment: @MKY Doesn't change my answer much. There is still a length word, and you still aren't sending it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to flush the Stream.
You need to add outToServer.flush() after the call to outToServer.writeBytes(message);

```
Log.d(TAG,"TCP Connected.");
outToServer.writeBytes(message);
outToServer.flush(); // <---- Add this line
modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
Log.d(TAG,modifiedSentence);
Log.d(TAG,"sucess");
```

Comment: Neither `DataOutputStream` nor the socket's output stream is buffered, so flushing them does nothing.