# Send XML Document and JSON as bytes over web socket in Java

Tags: java, json, xml, sockets

What are the benefits of using ByteArrayOutputStream to convert the XML or JSON data to send over web socket instead of sending these values as Strings?

Comment: For example, why do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428075/how-to-send-xml-data-through-socket-inputstream/2441736#2441736 instead of sending in String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Security:** JSON and XML easy to decode.(mostly for WS / compare to WSS)
2. **Efficiency:** In traffic usage and in most case encode/decode processing. Byte-Arrays could be very compact compare to string, specially with data that are not string by nature (compare 4-bytes Boolean array of size 32 with over 128 (32*4) byte need for string representation, both data usage and encode/decode CPU usage). check [THIS](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/being-fast-and-light-using-binary-data-to-optimise-libraries-on-the-client-and-the-server-5709f06ef105) link
3. **Generality:** Sending all type of data including any objects with complex hierarchical inheritances between them. In order to decode JSON with complex Tree-Like inheritance, you need very complex parsing method.
4. **Simplicity:** Enable to chunk data meaningfully. suppose we always use first 2 byte  of data as it's type. (to decode the rest). Normally additional libraries do that for us.
5. **Integrity:** Easily recognizing corrupted data. Even without checksum, 1-bit data-corruption could be detected in most case.
6. **Compatibility**: Using serialized object with version to control compatibility. (version control)-Although you could add version in JSON, it could cause many difficulty, inefficiency and trouble. check [THIS](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serial-version-uid)

And probably other reasons in special cases.